# How to get TotalByteSent and Referrer from minio log

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, minio

In the AWS S3 server access log we can get the response size in bytes, AWS named it “TotalBytesSent”. Also we got a “referrer”,  which indicates the HTTP referer that was set in the request header. Is there any way to get ***TotalBytesSent*** and ***Referrer*** from ***minio***? I've looked at the minio Audit log and Bucket notification, but didn't find it.

Amazon S3 server access log format reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/LogFormat.html

Comment: Please post the current log object if any ?

Answer (score 0):

The [minio log structure](https://docs.min.io/minio/baremetal/monitoring/logging/minio-logging.html) includes HTTP request and response headers. If a referrer is set in the request, it will appear in the `Referer` request header. The closest thing to `TotalBytesSent` will be the `Content-Length` response header.